# API resolved without sending a response for /api/repositories, this may result in stalled requests

Tags: node.js, next.js, server-sent-events

I use NextJS API interfaces as Server Sent Events as follows:

```
const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {

    ...
    ...

    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/event-stream;charset=utf-8");
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-transform");
    res.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");

    const observer: Observer<RepoInformation> = {
        next: value => {
            res.write(`event: received\n`);
            res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(value)}\n\n`);
        },
        error: (err: Error) => {
            res.write(`event: data-error\n`);
            res.write(`data: ${err.message}\n\n`);
        },
        complete: () => {
            console.log("Do nothing!!!");
        },
    };

    await
        access$.pipe(mergeMap(svc.repo.listRepos$))
        .subscribe(observer);
};

export default withApiAuthRequired(handler);
```

SSE works as expected except it shows in the console the following message:

```
API resolved without sending a response for /api/repositories, this may result in stalled requests.
```

My assumption is, because the connection is not closed by `res.end()`. However, why should I close the connection? I use the API as `SSE`.

The question is, is there something wrong with the server setup or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the warnings you can add a [custom config](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/api-middlewares#custom-config) to your API route with `externalResolver` set to `true`.

> `externalResolver` is an explicit flag that tells the server that this route is being handled by an external resolver like express or connect. Enabling this option disables warnings for unresolved requests.

```js
export const config = {
    api: {
        externalResolver: true
    }
}
```